# Unable to reproduce tensorflow results even after setting random seed

Tags: python, tensorflow, random-seed

To be able to perform hyperparameter optimization, I guess one should better set the random seed so we will better compare the models. So I set the random seed in tensorflow through: `tf.set_random_seed(mseed)`, and I created an initializer as: `kernel_initializer = tf.glorot_normal_initializer(seed=mseed)` whereI passed the later into the `LSTM` cell. So the model will be as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def lstm_model(lstm_model(inputs, cell_size1, kernel_initializer, m_dtype, dropout, is_training, use_peepholes, mseed, num_classes):

    with tf.variable_scope('lstm_model'):

        cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(cell_size1, initializer=kernel_initializer)
        initial_state = cell.zero_state(34 if is_training else 14, dtype=tf.float32)

        output, new_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, dtype=m_dtype, initial_state=initial_state)


    with tf.variable_scope("output"):
        output = tf.reshape(output, shape=[-1, cell_size1])
        output = tf.layers.dense(output, units=num_classes,
                                 kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer)

        if is_training:
            output = tf.reshape(output, shape=[34, -1, num_classes])
        else:
            output = tf.reshape(output, shape=[14, -1, num_classes])

        return output, new_state, initial_state, model_summary


def model(inputs..., mseed, kernel_initializer, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope('model', reuse=reuse):

        output, new_state, initial_state, model_summary = lstm_model(inputs, num_units,
                                                                     kernel_initializer,
                                                                     tf.float32, dropout, not reuse, True,
                                                                     mseed, num_classes=num_classes)

    # Now I calculate the loss and used an optimizer in case of training...
    return output, new_state, initial_state, model_summary

mseed = 123
seed(mseed)
tf.set_random_seed(mseed)
kernel_initializer = tf.glorot_normal_initializer(seed=mseed)

# here I loaded the data as numpy arrays...
# Here I created the placeholders...

# t for train, and d for development
output_t, new_state_t, init_state_t = model(inputs_t..., mseed, kernel_initializer, reuse=False)
output_d, new_state_d, init_state_d = model(inputs_d..., mseed, kernel_initializer, reuse=True)

train_model()...
```

So the code is summarized to include only the important part of it.

Now even after setting the random seed and using a `mseed` when creating the kernels, yet I cannot reproduce the same results.

Here is a screen shot for the accuracy and loss over time. We can see that the values are the same almost at the beginning and then they become different.

[image]

[image]

I would like to know where I could be mistaken or at least what part to debug of the code. Finally, please note that through out training, I am feeding back the last hidden state into the initial state at each batch. as follows:

```
new_state_train_py = sess.run(initiale_state_train)
    for i in range(num_iterations):
        _, summary_t, new_state_train_py = sess.run([train_step, summary_train, new_state_train],
                                feed_dict={train_x_ph: train_x[:, i*time_steps: (i + 1) * time_steps, :],
                                           train_y_ph: train_y[:, i*time_steps: (i + 1) * time_steps, :],
                                           initiale_state_train: new_state_train_py})

        train_writer.add_summary(summary_t, epoch * num_iterations + i)
```

What I know so far is that the main problem should be in the model definition since this what defines any randomness in the whole model and this is what makes the prediction different between the different runs of the same model. Please correct me if I am mistaken.

**After debugging, I noticed that when I changed the dtype for each op in the graph to tf.float64, I found that both curves totally intersect except at the end, I get another slight changes in the curves. What could be causing this behavior?**

[image]
[image]

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: What is `seed(mseed)`? Is it python's random.seed()?

Comment: Oh, it's `from numpy.random import seed`@openmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running code on a GPU, it is likely due to the non-deterministic behavior of cuDNN (see [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/718YYXwaYEk) for more details). The order in which some operations are executed on a GPU can be random due to performance optimizations. This means that rounding errors also occur in a different order, which leads to small differences in the result of these operations. In your case, these small differences add up over the course of training, which leads to significantly different behavior already after a few training steps.

The order of magnitude of the rounding errors depends on the floating point precision used by the GPU. With `float64`, the rounding errors take a lot longer to add up noticeably than with `float32`.

On a CPU, this non-deterministic behavior should not occur when python's, `numpy`'s and `tensorflow`'s random seeds are fixed (and op parallelism is deactivated, more info [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development)). So, if you run your code on a CPU, you should get the same results for every run (but that of course takes a lot longer).

Comment: Yes I am running it on a GPU GTX 1080 Ti

Comment: Sorry, my initial question was meant to be a comment, but I've edited the answer to be an explanation for the non-deterministic behavior.

Comment: I would like to add something on top of it: When I used different dataset, with vector dimensions of 100 compared to the initial dataset that I was using where each vector has dimension of 512, I found that I got the same exact curves of the accuracy and the rmse (in the later dataset); so can I assume that I have less calculation so less error to be added up?

Comment: Yes, I think that is a reasonable explanation, although I don't know exactly which TensorFlow ops give deterministic results and which ops give non-deterministic results on a GPU. This also seems to change [from version to version](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3103).