# Same seed number & package versions & python version but different neural net result from laptop and desktop

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm using a simple vanilla neural network like this,

```
reset_seeds(42)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_shape = (train_X_arr.shape[1], ), activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'mae')
```

The function named `reset_seeds` is defined below.

```
def reset_seeds(seed):
    import random
    import os
    import tensorflow as tf

    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    random.seed(seed)
    tf.random.set_seed(seed)
```

Then I check the initial weights of the model in my laptop and the desktop

**Laptop's sum of initial weights (Before training)**

> [-9.959677, 0.0, -5.590966, 0.0, -1.1521256, 0.0]

**Desktop's sum of initial weight (Before training)**

> [-9.959677, 0.0, -5.590966, 0.0, -1.1521256, 0.0]

However, after I run the model defined above with one epoch, the sum of initial weights is different between my laptop and desktop.

```
hist = model.fit(x = train_X_arr, y = train_y_arr, batch_size = 1, epochs = 1, verbose = 2, shuffle = False)
```

**Laptop's sum of initial weights (After training)**

> [-168.1607, -6.258976, 50.797672, 0.42788112, 0.15801406, -0.26924044]

**Desktop's sum of initial weight (After training)**

> [-159.85245, -5.7658424, 57.23868, 0.47032726, 0.13733912, -0.25829855]

I expected that the sum of the initial weight would be the **same** after the training because I set the random seed before compiling and training the model.

However, the result seems quite different.

I tried to figure out this for a whole week but I failed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to reproduce tensorflow results even after setting random seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53396670/unable-to-reproduce-tensorflow-results-even-after-setting-random-seed)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem that the result was not reproduced between my laptop and desktop.

But I don't know exactly how this work.

I fixed the code in this way.

**Original One**

```
reset_seeds(42)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_shape = (train_X_arr.shape[1], ), activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'mae')
```

**New One**

```
reset_seeds(42)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_shape = (train_X_arr.shape[1], ), activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mae') # Only this line changed
```

I think that this phenomenon is peculiar because the reproducibility was affected by its `optimizer` even if I set the seed to 42.

To my knowledge, I know that the default optimizer was `rmsprop`.

I will leave more comments if I precisely find out what was the problem.

Any comment will be helpful also.